# Why is method Equals called only once for two comparisons?

Tags: c#, equals

Consider the following simple program.

```
using System;


namespace CompareClasses
{

    class A
    {
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nHi, It is me A!");
            return base.Equals(obj);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a1 = new A();
            A a2 = new A();
            A a3 = a1;

            Console.WriteLine("compare a1 to a2: {0}", Equals(a1, a2));
            Console.WriteLine("compare a1 to a3: {0}", Equals(a1, a3));
        }
    }
}
```

Its output is the following

```
Hi, It is me A!
compare a1 to a2: False
compare a1 to a3: True
```

So the question is why was message Hi, It is me A! displayed only once?

Though if to see the MSIL code then we can see that static method `Equals` is called twice.

```
  IL_000f:  ldstr      "compare a1 to a2: {0}"
  IL_0014:  ldloc.0
  IL_0015:  ldloc.1
  IL_0016:  call       bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object,
                                                            object)
  IL_001b:  box        [mscorlib]System.Boolean
  IL_0020:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string,
                                                                object)
  IL_0025:  nop
  IL_0026:  ldstr      "compare a1 to a3: {0}"
  IL_002b:  ldloc.0
  IL_002c:  ldloc.2
  IL_002d:  call       bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object,
                                                            object)
  IL_0032:  box        [mscorlib]System.Boolean
  IL_0037:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string,
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how is that `Equals` called when it's executed from `Program` on no object in particular?

Comment: @Gusman  My question is clear enough. I asked about the static method.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel  There is called static method of class object that accepted to arguments of type A.

Comment: Did not saw the static, if you call Object.Equals it will do a first discard pase using object handle/hash, then as a1 is a3 its being discarded without calling your function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`object.Equals(obj1, obj2)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx) will first use `object.ReferenceEquals` to check if both objects are the same reference. This is true for a1 and a3.

From MSDN:

> The static Equals(Object, Object) method indicates whether two
>   objects, objA and objB, are equal. It also enables you to test objects
>   whose value is null for equality. It compares objA and objB for
>   equality as follows:

1. It determines whether the two objects represent the same object reference. If they do, the method returns true. This test is equivalent to calling the `ReferenceEquals` method. In addition
2. if both `objA` and `objB` are `null`, the method returns true. It determines whether either `objA` or `objB` is `null`. If so, it returns false. If the two objects do not represent the same object reference and neither is null,
3. it calls `objA.Equals(objB)` and returns the result. This means that if `objA` overrides the `Object.Equals(Object)` method, this override is called.

That's the reason why only this will call your overriden `Equals`:

```
Console.WriteLine("compare a1 to a2: {0}", Equals(a1, a2));
```

since both objects are different references and both are not null.

Comment: Could you give the reference to the cited quote?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: click the linked MSDN page

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: it is in [`object.Equals(obj1, obj2)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx) at the _Remarks_ section  ;-)

Comment: @Tim Schmelter It seems that the Russian description differs.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter  I have understood what is the problem. Your quote is in C# 4.5 but I read C# 4.0.:) Now I have seen C# 4.5 and the text the same as in your quote. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter  You can compare the English descriptions in C# 4.5 and C# 4.0 yourself.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: the remarks section seems to be equal, isn't it? [This is .NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [this is .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Tim Schmelter  No, the they differ. This is for C# 4 http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.100).aspx
 and this is for C# 4.5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: now you've posted the same links that i've posted in my last comment, just with russian language. But you've mentioned that i could "compare the English descriptions in C# 4.5 and C# 4.0 yourself". That's what i've done and both remarks are identical.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter You can compare visually the references I pointed out and you will see that they differ.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `Program.Equals(object, object)` (and since `Program` does not override `Equals` of the implicit `object` base class, `System.Object.Equals` is called effectively). It has an early exit for reference-equal objects:

```
if(ReferenceEquals(o1, o2)) { return true; }
else return o1.Equals(o2); // only here get's your override bool Equals(object other) called
```

(Similar to the above. It also checks for nulls, obviously)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the Equals method on Object that takes two parameters.  Which can be seen below decompiled:

```
public static bool Equals(Object objA, Object objB) 
    {
        if (objA==objB) {
            return true;
        } 
        if (objA==null || objB==null) {
            return false; 
        } 
        return objA.Equals(objB);
    }
```

The first time you call this method when you compare a1 to a2 you are using two different instances of A.  Therefore your method will be called on the last line above return objA.Equals(objB).

The second time you call this method you are passing the same instance of A.  As you set a3 equal to a1.  Therefore the line if (objA==objB) will be true so it will just shortcut at that point and return true and never call your overridden method.

Comment: This will throw a NPE when `objA` is null, but `objB` is non-null (granted, it's just pseudo code)